# Invoke iPhone Calculator at runtime.

Tags: ios

Is it possible to start the iPhone calculator from within an iOS app?
I find it really annoying to have to leave an app and open the calculator just to "trig out" a right triangle and then return to the original app.  I have a calculator class of my own however I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel for my app; especially with all the edge cases involved with Trig. 
Can anyone offer some insight whether this is possible or suggest a possible implementation?

Answer (score 0):

No, the calculator app doesn't have a public schema that you can use
 to invoke it